# ASP.NET Core relation is in database but is not retrieved

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am new to ASP.NET Core and I am trying to setup basic relationship with EntityFramework Core. I have a NavigationCategory class that has 1:M relationship with WebPage class. The relationship is understood by my DB (It has a foreign key) but when retrieving the WebPage from repository, it has no NavigationCategory, even though it has NavigationCategoryId set.

```
public class WebPage : BaseEntity
{
    private string _route;

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("NavigationCategory")]
    public long NavigationCategoryId { get; set; }

    public NavigationCategory NavigationCategory { get; set; }

    public WebPage()
    {
    }
}

public class NavigationCategory : BaseEntity
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<WebPage> WebPages { get; set; }

    public NavigationCategory()
    {
    }
}
```

This is simple BaseEntity:

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
}
```

This is my DB context:

```
public class AppDataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public DbSet<KinderClass> KinderClasses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Feed> Feeds { get; set; }
    public DbSet<NavigationCategory> NavigationCategories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<WebPage> WebPages { get; set; }

    public AppDataContext(DbContextOptions<AppDataContext> options) : base(options)
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<WebPage>()
            .HasOne(wp => wp.NavigationCategory)
                    .WithMany(c => c.WebPages)
                    .HasForeignKey(wp => wp.NavigationCategoryId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data). Lazy loading is not supported yet, you have to explicitly or eager load (using `Include` / `ThenInclude`) the related data.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly include any navigation property you want included when you fetch entities using EF Core. For example, update your query as follows:

```
var webpage = dbContext.WebPages
  .Include(w => w.NavigationCategory)
  .FirstOrDefault();
```

Note, you need these two namespaces, at minimum:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Linq;
```

Learn more about [loading related data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) and why [lazy loading shouldn't be used in web apps](http://ardalis.com/avoid-lazy-loading-entities-in-asp-net-applications).